# Dynamic rnn for toysequence classification

Tags: tensorflow

i am trying to use the dynamic rnn for toy sequence clasification . the code is copied from github link as:https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/dynamic_rnn.py.
The errors i am getting during predc function are as:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    509                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 510                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    511           except TypeError as err:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
   1103     if ret is None:
-> 1104       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1105

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
    946         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r" %
--> 947         (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
    948   return t

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("Reshape_4:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 pred = dynamicRNN(x, seqlen, weights, biases)

in dynamicRNN(x, seqlen, weights, biases)
      2     x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
      3     x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
----> 4     x = tf.split(0, seq_max_len, x)
      5     lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden)
      6     outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seqlen)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in split(value, num_or_size_splits, axis, num, name)
   1389   if size_splits._rank() == 0 and size_splits.dtype.is_integer:
   1390     return gen_array_ops.split(
-> 1391         axis=axis, num_split=num_or_size_splits, value=value, name=name)
   1392 
   1393   if num is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in split(axis, value, num_split, name)
   7707     num_split = _execute.make_int(num_split, "num_split")
   7708     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
-> 7709         "Split", split_dim=axis, value=value, num_split=num_split, name=name)
   7710     _result = _op.outputs[:]
   7711     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    531             if input_arg.type != types_pb2.DT_INVALID:
    532               raise TypeError("%s expected type of %s." %
--> 533                               (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(input_arg.type).name))
    534             else:
    535               # Update the maps with the default, if needed.

TypeError: Input 'split_dim' of 'Split' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of int32.

​